# existen group by anidados en pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera hacer como un group by anidado de tal manera que me quede una tabla dinámica con el siguiente estilo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pensé en hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
nivel_edu = final_df[[' Computer_OS','Employee_ID']].groupby(' Computer_OS').count()

nivel_edu ['Education_Level']= final_df['Education_Level'].count()
nivel_edu
```

pero no me queda, alguien tiene una sugerencia?

Comment: En parte es con un `group_by` pero en primer lugar tienes que crear una tabla pivote que sea el producto cartesiano de Computer_OS y Education_Level. Si armas un [mcve]  va a ser más fácil poder ayudarte

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Patricio, me diste una gran pista, con eso ya pude resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

nivel_edu = pd.pivot_table(final_df,index=[' Computer_OS','Education_Level'],aggfunc={'Employee_ID':np.size})

Ahora sólo quiero investigar cómo ordenar la columna de employee_ID de mayor a menor, tendrás alguna pista?

Answer (score 0):

La función para contar la repetición de la agrupación es `size()` y necesitas especificar las columnas por las que agrupar en el parámetro `by` de la función `groupby`.

```py
nivel_edu = final_df.groupby(by=['Computer_OS','Education_Level']).size()
nivel_edu
```

Si quieres que el resultado te aparezca como un `DataFrame` deberías usar a continuación:

```py
nivel_edu.to_frame()
```